# Setting fixed width of Button component

Tags: qt, qml

I'm starting with QML. I trying to build a simple component (for a chat window) that is a horizontal gray rectangle containing a textfield and a button.
The rectangl should take the entire horizontal space of its parent. The buttton on the right should have a fixed with and the textfield takes up the remaining space.

The problem: I cannot set the button width to a fixed value. I tried to set the width-property but that doesn't have any effect.

Here my code so far:

App.qml:

```
import QtQuick 6.2
import QtQuick.Window 6.2
import Test1

Window {
    width: 600
    height: 800

    visible: true
    title: "Test1"

    Screen01 {
        id: mainScreen
    }
}
```

Screen01.ui.qml:

```
import QtQuick 6.2
import QtQuick.Controls 6.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 6.2
import Test1

Rectangle {
    id: rectangle
    height: 50
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.right: parent.right
    color: "#555";

    RowLayout {
        id: chatInputLayout
        anchors.fill : parent

        TextField {
            id: chatInputField
            placeholderText: "Write something ..."
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.margins: 5
        }

        Button {
            id: chatSendButton
            width: 200
            //Layout.fillWidth: true
            text: "send"
            Layout.topMargin: 5
            Layout.rightMargin: 5
            Layout.bottomMargin: 5
            Layout.leftMargin: 0
            Connections {
                onClicked: function() {
                    console.log("text", chatInputField.text)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `Layout.preferredWidth` https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html#preferredWidth-attached-prop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **smr** already commented, you can use `Layout.preferredWidth` in order to achieve a static width for the button. The shared documentation also mentions that `implicitWidth` can also be used which I commented out in the snippet below.

> If the preferred width is -1 it will be ignored, and the layout will
> use implicitWidth instead.

```
Rectangle {
    id: rectangle
    height: 50
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.right: parent.right
    color: "#555"

    RowLayout {
        id: chatInputLayout
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 5
        spacing: 5

        TextField {
            id: chatInputField
            placeholderText: qsTr("Write something ...")
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }

        Button {
            id: chatSendButton
            width: 200
            //implicitWidth: chatSendButton.width
            Layout.preferredWidth: chatSendButton.width
            text: qsTr("Send")

            Connections {
                function onClicked() {
                    console.log("Send.onClicked", chatInputField.text)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the additional tip with implicitWidth